# Regex to split text only if followed by the given pattern

Tags: regex

I want to split a given text on spaces if they are followed by the given pattern.

For example, if the input text is `Hi [abcde123AB:abcde123AB] more text` then the expected output is,

```
Hi,
[abcde123AB:abcde123AB],
more text
```

I came up with the regex `\s+,?[(U[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{10}):(B[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{10})\\]` but its producing the below incorrect output.

```
Hi [abcde123AB:abcde123AB],
ore,
ext
```

I was reading [this](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) article to understand the concept of lookahead but unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\w` is same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` hence you can write `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{10}` as `[\w-]{10}` and using [lookarounds](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html), you can write your regex as following,

```
 (?=\[[\w-]{10}:[\w-]{10}\])|(?<=\[[\w-]{10}:[\w-]{10}\])
```

Notice the space at the beginning of the regex and at the end of regex

What you want is, a space followed by `[abcde123AB:abcde123AB]` pattern or a space preceded by `[abcde123AB:abcde123AB]` pattern.

Also in case you want to generalize a single space with multiple space then you can use  `+` or `\s+` which will cover any whitespace or even use `\h+` to account for only horizontal space which covers space and tabs.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/V41Oe1/1)

Comment: This is what I was looking for! what if I want to extend this regex to split by new lines as well, ex: "Hi [abcde123AB:abcde123AB] more text\n\nmore text" should output "Hi"," [abcde123AB:abcde123AB]"," more text","\n","\n","more text".
 (?=\[[\w-]{10}:[\w-]{10}])|(?<=\[[\w-]{10}:[\w-]{10}]) |\n did't include the new lines in the output.

Comment: Additionally, splitting by any newline, just put an or condition and `\n` but if you splitting by newline, you shouldn't expect newline in your results like space is not there in your results.

Answer (score 0):

In some languages like for example JavaScript or Python, you can split using a capture group to keep that part in the result.

In this case you can match optional surrounding whitespace characters, and capture the part with the square brackets in group 1.

**Note** that the example in your question does not have  `[U` or `:B` for your pattern to match.

```js
const s = "Hi [abcde123AB:abcde123AB] more text";
const regex = /\s*(\[[\w-]{10}:[\w-]{10}])\s*/;
console.log(s.split(regex));
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1W50oy/1).

Comment: Do you know how we could achieve the same with Java?

Comment: @Lakmal In Java, the split function does not keep the value of the capture group. If you only want to use split, you can use the lookaround assertion approach. Are there also rules to match `Hi` and `more text` ?

Comment: No, just the rules to match what inside [].